# Problema con la sobrecarga de operadores

Tags: c++, operador, compilador

Estoy desarrollando una clase TComplejo que presenta dos atributos, **double im** (parte imaginaria del numero complejo) e **double re** (parte real del complejo), pero me hallo atascado en la sobrecarga del operator*, en concreto en 2 sus versiones:

```cpp
TComplejo TComplejo::operator* (TComplejo number){
    TComplejo product;
    //Ecuaciones matemáticas que no vienen al caso para recalcular los atributos
    product.re = this->re * ...
    product.im = this->im * ...

    return product;
}
```

```cpp
TComplejo TComplejo::operator* (double real){
    //Llamo a un constructor que me crea un TComplejo a partir de un double
    TComplejo number(real);

    //Desreferencio el puntero this y llamo al operator* anterior
    return (*this)*number;
}
```

Como se puede observar, la primera sobrecarga no presenta ningún problema ya que lleva a cabo el procedimiento 'standar'; sin embargo, en el 2º al pasarnos solo uno de los atributos de TComplejo (su parte real), me veo obligado a llamar a uno de los constructores que me lo soluciona.

Una vez hecho esto, solo me quedaría resolver la problemática de multiplicar 2 datos del tipo TComplejo, justo de lo que se encarga el 1er operator*, por eso en el **return (*this)*number** desreferencio el puntero 'this' para obtener el objeto y llamo a dicho operador.

Al compilar me aparece el siguiente error:

> lib/tcomplejo.cpp: In member function 'TComplejo TComplejo::operator*(double)':
>    lib/tcomplejo.cpp:105:16: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'TComplejo' and 'TComplejo*')
>          return (*this)*number;

Sinceramente no se que estoy haciendo mal, ya se que puede implentar lo de un operador en otro haciendo 'Copy Paste' pero me gustaría que siguiera la dinámica que he comentado.

> tcomplejo.h

```
using namespace std;

class TComplejo{
  //FUNCIONES AMIGAS
  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream&, TComplejo&);
  friend TComplejo operator+(double, TComplejo&);
  friend TComplejo operator-(double, TComplejo&);
  friend TComplejo operator*(double, TComplejo&);

private:
  double re ;
  double im ; 

public:
  TComplejo (); 
  TComplejo (double ); 
  TComplejo (double , double); 
  TComplejo (TComplejo&); 
  ~TComplejo(); 

  TComplejo& operator=(TComplejo &); 

  //Sobrecarga de operadores
  TComplejo operator+(TComplejo &); 
  TComplejo operator-(TComplejo &); 
  TComplejo operator*(TComplejo &);

  TComplejo operator+(double) ; 
  TComplejo operator-(double) ; 
  TComplejo operator*(double) ; 

  bool operator==(TComplejo &); 
  bool operator!=(TComplejo &);

  //Getters
  double Re(); 
  double Im();

  double Arg(void); 
  double Mod(void); 

  //Setters
  void Re(double); 
  void Im(double);
};
```

Comment: He probado las implementaciones que muestras y a mi no me dan error alguno.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo insertar toda la declaración (.h) de la clase TComplejo aquí?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade ahí lo que necesites